# Changing width kendo ui select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui

Kendo UI, have a great function for styling select control.

Like this simple:

**Javascript**

```
$(".form-group").find("select:not([multiple])").kendoDropDownList().end()
```

**Html**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <select id="language">
   <option selected>English</option>
   <option>German</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

It changes the look of select dropdown, but i got problem, it changes and select width to some crazy px width like **174px**, but i want to have that value 100%, to parent element?
Does anybody have soution for that?

Comment: What is the purpose of the .end() method call here?

Comment: Sorry I'm confused! You have a kendoDropDownList but you want to resize the width of the DDL to take the 100% width of the container, right??

Comment: .k-widget.k-dropdown
{
 width:100%;
}
.k-widget.k-tabstrip > input.k-textbox
{
 width:100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this custom styling after the kendo ui css declaration:

**CSS**

```
span.k-dropdown {
   width: 100%;
}
```